# UIImageView animation lag

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I have a problem with the animation. At start, everything is smooth. However, when the application runs for a certain period of time (around 10 min) then the animation lags.

Here is the code in viewDidLoad:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And in -(void)updateImage: //image fade in

```
[aSubview release];
[aSubview removeFromSuperview];
aSubview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 64, 265, 284)];
aSubview.image = [slideShowArray objectAtIndex:randNum];
[aSubview setAlpha:0.0];
[UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[aSubview setAlpha:1.0];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
[self.view addSubview:aSubview];

UIImageView *film = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 34, 280, 344)];
film.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"film5.png"];
[film setAlpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:film];
[film release];
```

Can anyone explain this? Is it due to memory issue or something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `slideShow` and what is `aSubview`?

Comment: It's mostly a memory thing like others have mentioned. Is this the entire `updateImage:` method?

Comment: I have added the rest of the code, and modified a bit.

Comment: Now you are removing aSubview, but still have the film image. You should remove them too like aSubview if not needed. I have edited my answer.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved! Thank you everyone for your quick and constructive responses! This is why I love stackoverflow!! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.view addSubview:aSubview];
```

You are adding a subview in every 3 seconds. So after 10 mins there are 200 subviews which requires too much memory and thus slowing the app. Before adding a new subview, remove the previous ones if they are not needed. And if you need 200 subviews simultaneously then you should reconsider your design.

EDIT: After the edit of the question, why do you need to add a `film` every time? You are adding a new `film` object every time the method is called. Note that, super view retains subviews. So if the method is called 20 times then you have 20 `film` objects in memory.

Comment: @taskinoor The film is originally part of the code actually, I just modified the question to show the whole class. Will [film release], which I have added help?

Comment: +1ed this already. There is no reason to have multiple instances of `film` as subviews when they are not even spread out.

Comment: The film portion is part of updateImage which get called in every 3 seconds?

Comment: @taskinoor, @Deepak: The initial reason why I do so is that I want the film image to cover the aSubview image. Maybe i should put it in viewDidLoad and send the aSubview image to the back? Can this be done?

Comment: Add film in viewDidLoad and bring it to front by calling bringSubviewToFront.

Comment: Another way is you can use film just like aSubview. Make film a class member, and release and remove it from superview before the alloc just like yo did for aSubview.

Comment: @taskinoor: The problem seems really due to film as I am trying out the app without the film image. I thought by calling [film release] has solved the issue and never consider it again. Thx for pointing this out again and now I will try your method and see if it works!

Comment: Its because the super view retains the subviews. When the super view itself got dealloced, it releases all subviews.

Comment: @taskinoor: Thank you so much for your help, I think the problem is solved!

Comment: @ Others: Thank you very much four your advice as well!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem is with memory aggregating over time. To solve this problem use Instruments to check memory usage and find out what causes it. You might not release some object. In XCode go to Product -> Profile or press "cmd+i" choose "Allocations" and add "Leaks" manualy. Run Instruments and try to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:aSubview];
```

The above is not the issue at all, from  the apple documentation for `addSubView` .

> Views can have only one superview. If
>   view already has a superview and that
>   view is not the receiver, this method
>   removes the previous superview before
>   making the receiver its new superview.

**Animation** is always a **heavy operation in term of memory** that need to store many thing before and after animation, which are not visualable  to as application developer. And in your case you are doing it more than 10 min.. in a loop that lead to reduce the availability of memory for next animation operation.

Comment: I am afraid that the OP's aSubview is not the same at every call of updateImage. There is a high possibility that every time a new image view is getting added to the super view. Though that is not 100% sure from the question.

Comment: @taskinoor : Right, we would call it as bad practice but not the cause of problem ..

Comment: That will be the cause of the problem if you add 200 different subviews.

Comment: The problem still exists and so I added one more line:    [aSubview removeFromSuperview];
Now testing, hope it helps.

Comment: @ taskinoor  : It's related to memory that certain and you have a valid point here of adding 200 different view.